# How to search annotation in map

Tags: ios, swift, search, annotations, mapkit

I have a `mapView` in a `viewController` and i would like to add a search functionality to search my `annotations` based on `title` and `subtitle` and 2 people already asked for it but didnt get an answer as well so please if anyone can help with code or any guide please help

Guy #1 Question : [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859017/how-to-search-annotation-in-map-based-on-title-swift-2-2)

Guy #2 Question : [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088427/how-to-search-annotations-in-mapview-based-on-title-subtitle)

Comment: How did you get the data to show the annotations? Is it stored locally?

Comment: Perhaps you can share links to the other two questions. But you're searching amongst the annotations you've already added to the map, right? Not searching the region shown on the map for some address or establishment with the intent of creating an annotation, right?

Comment: Here are the links. I already have the annotation i would just like to have a search functionality to search those annotations cause i have like 25

Comment: "2 people already asked for it" I think you meant to say that _you_ already asked twice, using two of your other accounts.

Comment: Right. Clap clap clap

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to search the existing annotations for something that contained a particular string, I'd do something like the following in Swift 2:

```
let searchResults = mapView.annotations.filter { annotation in
    return (annotation.title??.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchTerm) ?? false) ||
        (annotation.subtitle??.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchTerm) ?? false)
}
```

Or, in Swift 3:

```
let searchResults = mapView.annotations.filter { annotation in
    return (annotation.title??.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm) ?? false) ||
        (annotation.subtitle??.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm) ?? false)
}
```

Comment: like he did where you press a button to open up a search but search annotations only as he said

Comment: That guy is doing `MKLocalSearchRequest`, to create new annotations, not for searching amongst his existing annotations. Perhaps I misunderstood, but that's different from what I thought you just asked about. And why would you search again amongst the search results? E.g., if you search for "joe's bar" with `MKLocalSearchRequest`, you will only get search results that match. So why do you want to take the search text you just use and filter the result by that search text? Maybe you should step back and describe the broader business problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Idk really what he has done but the way he describes it when he wants to have a search function that will help you find 1 annotation among many is just what i want

Comment: So, you do a `MKLocalSearchRequest` for "joe's bar" ... I'm not following what the benefit is for then searching that result set for "joe's bar" again. Maybe you can give an example.

Comment: im so confused dude lol maybe this will be better : like have a `searchbar` and you can search the annotations by an `array` of names or something  and then when the search bar will filter the results and u will click on the result you want it will zoom on the correct `pin` and show the `annotationView` ... is it possible? or did u understand xD

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you're doing `MKLocalSearch`, just search for what you want and be done with it. Or are you going to search for one string and then filter it again by another string? Or are you getting your list of annotations somewhere other than `MKLocalSearch`?

Comment: Lol dude im so confused hahaha i will ask differently ... If i have a lot of annotations how can i make the user find a specific annotation more easily? With some sort of search right?

Comment: I guess I was thrown off by your `MKLocalSearch` reference. OK, you have a lot of annotations added to your map by some means other than `MKLocalSearch` and you want to filter them by some string. Then you use the code I provided in my answer above, you look for all annotations that have that string somewhere in the `title` or `subtitle`. The `searchResults` will contain an array of annotations that match the filter criteria. So, what's the question then?

Comment: Sorry im such a newbie and im making everything much more complex and idk if its even possible but my question is basically for example you can search for a name lets say of a street and apple map will take you there and zoom on it... Is it possible to make the annotation like i search the name of it and it will zoom in on it ? or if u know anything else that will make me able to find a specific annotation out of many. Im open minded .